# How to integrate FedEx API web service with c# ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, fedex

Step by step integration of FedEx Web Service for Tracking Shipment Information...!

I have already downloaded the API Reference and whole api with FedEx site and try to connect with my website but when i click on the track button it shows only XML file and its details with my website.

Comment: I Think you need to parse/interpret that xml file.

Comment: Yeah. I am not going to try doing it this way. Shippo might be a better way to go. see the next answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an easy-to-use C# client library, you can check out [Shippo](https://goshippo.com) and their [C# client library](https://github.com/goshippo/shippo-csharp-client). It's an easy way to integrate FedEx in C# without manually integrating the FedEx Web Services directly (FedEx doesn't provide any wrappers for specific programming languages).

Comment: This answer appears to be correct. I found the Shippo libraries and got myself an account. I cannot verify that the shippo code is easy to use, but the libraries do compile. I also cannot verify that FedEx Web Services don't provide wrappers. But I certainly didn't see any.